# Why should I keep all data when reading external sources?

Tags: sesam

I've been told that I should try to use as raw data as possible and not filter or transform the data when reading them into the hub. Why is this so?

If I only need a subset of the inputdata, it seems much easier to just read that subset.

Answer (score 1):

The article on [Raw Input](https://github.com/sesam-community/wiki/wiki/Raw-Input) lists some pros and cons.